# Legal Form Between Two People Starting Company

Tags: contract-law

I'm starting a company with someone, however, we are working on creating a finalized beginning product first. What form(s) should I go about having us sign to essentially make it so neither of us can screw each other?

So I can't ditch the project with the product and neither can he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is called a partnership deed. There is nothing special about it; just write down the rights and obligations of both partners and put "signed as a deed" above your signatures.

Comment: One last thing, a lot of the Partnership Deeds I looked at require a specific state.  Our company will be internet based and we are not in the same state. What should I do?

Comment: Pick any state you like to be the governing law

Comment: It is a partnership agreement in NY, not a Partnership Deed.  If partnership is the corporate form you pick.  A partnership agreement may be appropriate but another corporate form like a pass-through LLC may or an LLP may make more sense.  You also need to work out how you will resolve disputes, etc... and should really talk to an attorney in NY.